# Use networkx in pycharm can’t creat an empty undirected graph graph()

Tags: python-2.7

```
import networkx as nx               
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt     

G = nx.Graph()
```

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Graph'

Comment: Did you call your file `networkx.py`?

Comment: I am new for python. Thank you very much!